# Text to Speech not working on Application relating to NFC

Tags: android, nfc, text-to-speech

Disclaimer: I am extremely new to Android Studio and App Developent so the code may be unorganized

I am currently trying to develop an app in which when you scan an NFC tag with plain text on it, it will say the text aloud through texttospeech (no button). However, when I try to scan the NFC tag, the text comes up but the texttospeech is not working.

Here is my MainActivity:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    public static final String Error_Detected = "No NFC Tag Detected";
    public static final String Write_Success = "Text Written Successfully!";
    public static final String Write_Error = "Error during Writing, Try Again!";
    NfcAdapter nfcAdapter;
    PendingIntent pendingIntent;
    IntentFilter writingTagFilters[];
    boolean writeMode;
    Tag myTag;
    Context context;
    TextView edit_message;
    TextView nfc_contents;
    Button ActivateButton;
    TextToSpeech mTTS;



@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    edit_message = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.edit_message);
    nfc_contents = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.nfc_contents);
    ActivateButton = findViewById(R.id.ActivateButton);
    context = this;


    ActivateButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            try {
                if(myTag ==null) {
                    Toast.makeText(context, Error_Detected, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                } else {
                    write("PlainText|"+edit_message.getText().toString(), myTag);
                    Toast.makeText(context, Write_Success, Toast.LENGTH_LONG ).show();
                }
            } catch (IOException e) {
                Toast.makeText(context, Write_Error, Toast.LENGTH_LONG ).show();
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (FormatException e) {
                Toast.makeText(context, Write_Error, Toast.LENGTH_LONG ).show();
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    });
    mTTS = new TextToSpeech(getApplicationContext(), new TextToSpeech.OnInitListener() {
        @Override
        public void onInit(int status) {
            String toSpeak = edit_message.getText().toString().trim();
            if (status != TextToSpeech.ERROR){
                //if there is no error then set language
                mTTS.setLanguage(Locale.UK);
            }
            else {
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Error", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
            {
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, toSpeak, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                //speak the text
                mTTS.speak(toSpeak, TextToSpeech.QUEUE_FLUSH, null);
            }
        }
    });
    nfcAdapter = NfcAdapter.getDefaultAdapter(this);
    if(nfcAdapter == null){
        Toast.makeText(this, "This device does not support NFC", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        finish();
    }
    readFromIntent(getIntent());
    pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, new Intent(this, getClass()).addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP), 0);
    IntentFilter tagDetected = new IntentFilter(NfcAdapter.ACTION_TAG_DISCOVERED);
    tagDetected.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_DEFAULT);
    writingTagFilters = new IntentFilter[] { tagDetected };
}
private void readFromIntent(Intent intent) {
    String action = intent.getAction();
    if (NfcAdapter.ACTION_TAG_DISCOVERED.equals(action)
        || NfcAdapter.ACTION_TECH_DISCOVERED.equals(action)
        || NfcAdapter.ACTION_NDEF_DISCOVERED.equals(action)) {
        Parcelable[] rawMsgs = intent.getParcelableArrayExtra(NfcAdapter.EXTRA_NDEF_MESSAGES);
        NdefMessage[] msgs = null;
        if (rawMsgs != null) {
            msgs = new NdefMessage [rawMsgs.length];
            for (int i = 0; i < rawMsgs.length; i++) {
                msgs[i] = (NdefMessage) rawMsgs[i];
            }
        }
        buildTagViews(msgs);
    }
}
private void buildTagViews(NdefMessage[] msgs) {
    if (msgs == null || msgs.length == 0) return;

    String text ="";

    byte[] payload = msgs[0].getRecords()[0].getPayload();
    String textEncoding = ((payload[0] & 128) == 0) ? "UTF-8" : "UTF-16";
    int languageCodeLength = payload[0] & 0063;

    try {
        text = new String(payload, languageCodeLength + 1, payload.length - languageCodeLength - 1, textEncoding);
    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
        Log.e("UnsupportedEncoding", e.toString());
    }

    nfc_contents.setText("NFC Content: " + text);
}
private void write(String text, Tag tag) throws IOException, FormatException {
    NdefRecord[] records = { createRecord(text) };
    NdefMessage message = new NdefMessage(records);
    Ndef ndef = Ndef.get(tag);

    ndef.connect();

    ndef.writeNdefMessage(message);

    ndef.close();
}
private NdefRecord createRecord(String text) throws UnsupportedEncodingException {
    String lang        ="en";
    byte[] textBytes   =text.getBytes();
    byte[] langBytes   =lang.getBytes("US-ASCII");
    int    langLength  =langBytes.length;
    int    textLength  =textBytes.length;
    byte[] payload     =new byte[1 + langLength + textLength];

    payload[0] = (byte) langLength;


    System.arraycopy(langBytes, 0, payload, 1, langLength);
    System.arraycopy(textBytes, 0, payload, 1+langLength,textLength);

    NdefRecord recordNFC = new NdefRecord(NdefRecord.TNF_WELL_KNOWN, NdefRecord.RTD_TEXT, new byte[0], payload);

    return recordNFC;
}


@Override
protected void onNewIntent(Intent intent) {
    super.onNewIntent(intent);
    setIntent(intent);
    readFromIntent(intent);
    if (NfcAdapter.ACTION_TAG_DISCOVERED.equals(intent.getAction())) {
        myTag = intent.getParcelableExtra(NfcAdapter.EXTRA_TAG);
    }
}


@Override
public void onPause(){
    super.onPause();
    WriteModeOff();
}

@Override
public void onResume(){
    super.onResume();
    WriteModeOn();
}

private void WriteModeOn(){
    writeMode = true;
    nfcAdapter.enableForegroundDispatch(this, pendingIntent, writingTagFilters, null);
}

private void WriteModeOff(){
    writeMode = false;
    nfcAdapter.disableForegroundDispatch(this);
}
}
```

Comment: 1. Are you sure there is no error? Do you see the toast from the line just before the `mTTS.speak()` call? 2. The structure of `onInit` is wrong - if there is an error the app will try to speak anyway, because you call `speak()` after the `if - else` clause. You should call to `speak()` only if there is no error.

Comment: I think your ordering of events might be wrong But you don't show how you are handling getting the text from the NFC card. The way I read it is 1.  Application starts `onCreate` called both `edit_message` and `nfc_contents` are initialised as empty, you then speak `edit_message`,  2. `onResume` is called,  3.then at some point later the NFC card is read and probably puts it's text in to `nfc_contents` but I don't see any code that speaks (`mTTS.speak`)  `nfc_contents` after the card has been read which is well after `onCreate` is called. You need to show your NFC reading code.

Comment: Okay sorry about that. I now updated the post so that the entire MainActivity code is shown.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My understanding of `TextToSpeech` in the `onInit` method you just need to setup text to speech engine, it does not watch a particular widget and speak everything that is in it and does so every time it changes.

To get it to speak the text stored on the NFC card

In `buildTagViews` method after the line `nfc_contents.setText("NFC Content: " + text);` add

```
mTTS.speak(text, TextToSpeech.QUEUE_FLUSH, null);
```

Because currently you are never instructing the Text to speech engine to speak what is on the NFC card. Because currently you are only instructing the Text to speech engine to speak the words that are in the `TextView` just after you have initialised it from the xml (so most likely empty).

Also you could probably remove the code in the `onInit` below because it is redundant (unless you set some text to the edit widget in your layout xml) and has additional `{}`'s

```
{
   Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, toSpeak, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
   //speak the text
   mTTS.speak(toSpeak, TextToSpeech.QUEUE_FLUSH, null);
}
```